# Error when using eval(x) inside library where x is a string

Tags: r, eval

I am trying to understand tidyeval. Why does the below error occur?

```
x <- "dplyr"
library(eval(x))
## Error in library(eval(x)) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `character.only` option as `TRUE` in `library` which is by default `FALSE`

```
library(x, character.only = TRUE)
```

> character.only - a logical indicating whether package or help can be assumed to be character strings.

-testing on a fresh `R` session

```
> x <- "dplyr"
> library(x, character.only = TRUE)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

---

Regarding the error, it occurs from the following step (if we debug the function) i.e. it does a `substitute` on the code when the `character.only` is `FALSE` (by default) and this results in creating a vector of length 2 when it is converted to `character` (`as.character`)

```
> debugonce(library)
...

browse[2]> 
debug: lib.loc <- lib.loc[dir.exists(lib.loc)]
Browse[2]> 
debug: if (!character.only) package <- as.character(substitute(package))
Browse[2]> 
debug: package <- as.character(substitute(package))
Browse[2]> 
debug: if (length(package) != 1L) stop("'package' must be of length 1")
Browse[2]> 
debug: stop("'package' must be of length 1")
Browse[2]> 
Error in library(eval(x)) : 'package' must be of length 1
```

i.e. internally, the codes does `substitute` and the output is of `length` 2 here

```
as.character(substitute(eval(x)))
[1] "eval" "x"
```

which throws the error on the check

Comment: I should have said I was aware of that option; but I'm instead trying to understand why eval() specifically won't work. Specifically when compared to

    `x <- "height"`

    `with(starwars,  eval(x))`